# Touch screen monitor doesn't work with USB-A plugged in, but it works with OTG cable

Tags: usb, display, touchscreen, usb-c

I have a touch screen monitor with the following ports:

- USB-C PD (for power)
- USB-C Data (for touch + video) - Thunderbolt and USB 3.1 supported
- HDMI
- USB-A (for a mouse, keyboard, etc)

On my Raspberry Pi Zero W I use an USB Micro-B to USB-A female OTG cable to connect to the USB-C Data port on the monitor, then I connect HDMI between the two devices, and finally power to the monitor. That works perfectly.

However, when I try to connect my Raspberry Pi 4 by using an USB-A to USB-C cable, the touch does not work. Even weirder, when I disconnect the data, the screen goes black for a few seconds and the speaker makes a pop sound (like it's trying to power the monitor from the Raspberry Pi).

If I connect my phone to the monitor with a USB-C to USB-C cable, it charges my phone, it receives a video signal from my phone, and it transfers touch from the screen to the phone.

**This works:**

[image]

**This does not work:**

[image]

What's wrong here? As far as I know, there are no "reverse" USB-C OTG cables/adapters. I need an USB-A to USB-C OTG cable, essentially. A cable that only transfers data in one direction (from the monitor to the Raspberry Pi).